# Views Objects Removed from Grid Layout While Rotating and Pushing lock button together

Tags: java, android

I created an array of imageView size = 768 and Linear layout 768. Content of Views are  updated in every 15 sec.

Scenario has been changed from previous one. I found out the Actual Scenario.
I add and remove imageView inside a linearLayout both in an array, image changes based on user request or remotely from a server. Problem is when my app rotates and while rotating i press the lock button the phone goes on sleep mode. When i unlock the device all views are removed from the grid layout. It's Blank as all code in try catch.

Each image is in linearLayout. All of Linear layouts are in a  grid layout Which is parent.

It gives an error & app crashes when i unlock the device :
ArrayOutofBounds index = 96 length 12, while my array size is 768.
How it is possible that my array size changes on sleep. 
Sequence is:

```
  //to add new imageView Objects
try{
    for(..)
    {
     linearArray[i].RemoveAllViews()  //this line shows error on sleep device
     setImage(ImageArray[i]);
     linearArray[i].addView(imageArray[i])  
     linearArray[i].requestlayout(); 
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{
//print Stacktrac..
}
```

Pls help. Why isthis happening, iv'e been searching this for days.

Regards.

Comment: If you get an arrayOutOfBounds Exception on that line, the actual error (size of array changeing) occured somewhere else. Please post more of your code.

Comment: No Size of array does not changes any where in code.

Answer (score 0):

When you send to background your app, you can lose some variables.Here's [onPause n onReseme](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) Check Activity Lifecycle and Fragment Lifecycle, and how to save and get your variables , i hope help you.